# Google maps on a self hosted website

Tags: google-maps, self-hosting

I've a small self-hosted website hosted on my home server via no-ip.com, wonder if it's legit/possible to use Google maps on it and what would be the viable options if not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean with "to use Google maps on it"?

If you just want to allow your users to see a map and navigate on it, it is possible. Google has published a SDK (Google Maps API) that allows other people to interrogate Google servers, collect data (maps), show maps to users and perform a few operations related to positioning and navigation. There is a web (javascript) toolkit for this here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Other info here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

If you want to host a clone of the Google Mpas service on your PC, then no, this is not possible (both for legal and technical reasons).

A well-known, largely appreciated alternative to Google Maps is openstreetmap:

http://openstreetmap.org/